# Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row (Mas não faz sentido)

Tags: mysql

Tenho a necessidade de saber o número de registro de uma tabela agrupados por método, e tenho também a necessidade de ter o número de registro dos positivos por dos métodos positivos, isso tudo por usuário. Fiz algo semelhante em outra tabela funcionou mas nessa não. (estou usando mysql)

```
SELECT 
  busines.method_id, 
  m.name Metodo, 
  count(busines.id) Nro_busines, 
  ifnull(
    (
      select 
        (
          count(b.profit) nro_lucros 
          from 
            busines b 
            join busines on b.id = busines.id 
            and b.method_id = busines.method_id 
            and b.user_id = busines.user_id 
          where 
            b.user_id = "1598521" 
            and b.profit >= 0 
          group by 
            b.method_id
        ), 
        0
    ) as nro_lucros 
    FROM 
      busines 
      join methods m on m.id = busines.method_id 
      and m.user_id = busines.user_id 
    where 
      busines.user_id = "1598521" 
    group by 
      busines.method_id
```

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Chave da tabela busines somente id
Chave da metodos somente id

Comment: `b.profit >= 0` gera a possibilidade de mais de um resultado e `ifnull()` exige um singleton.

Comment: acho que o `b.profit >= 0` não é a causa pq ele está no `where` que retorna um `count` que vai retornar só um valor, mas o `ifnull()` é que pode estar atrapalhando ai como o @AugustoVasques comentou, mas o que mais acho que é o problema é o fato de usar um `group by`, se houverem diferentes `method_id`  vai ter mais de um resultado, a subquery tem de garantir um único resultado, execute ela em separado e tira a duvida, vais achar o problema

Comment: A subquery tem um "group by" , porquê ?

Comment: Eu tenho uma group by dentro da subquery para poder contar todos os métodos que estão positivos. não faz sentido? Já removi o ifnull etc , mas não consegui